# Customize where clause condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I need to customize where clause based on an input from HTML form. For instance, if a user didn't populate the ready field. I want the select query to return items that have any value for ready field including null else return a match for the value entered by the user.

```
declare @name varchar(max) = '%%'

declare @state  varchar(max) = '%%'

declare @ready  varchar(max) = '%%'

select *

from DummyTable

where   ([name] like  @name ) and 

        ([state] like @state ) AND 

        ([ready] LIKE @ready OR [ready] = case when @ready = '' then null else '' end  )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help you in **your code**. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read through the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask a question that is acceptable in the forum. If you have tried any code please paste it above so someone can help you on it.

Comment: I think you mean `COALESCE([ready], @ready) like @ready` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
where   ([name] like  @name OR @name is NULL) and 

        ([state] like @state OR @state is NULL ) AND 

        ([ready] LIKE @ready OR @ready is NULL)
```

So when any value wasn't entered there is no need to filter this field